# Is anyone still using Atom?

Tags: rest, atom-feed

I am currently reading "REST in Practice", which is getting a bit long in the tooth by technical book standards (2009), but it came highly recommended to me as a book that still has a lot of pertinent information for today's world.  One of the topics that has particularly caught my interest is the use of Atom feeds to publish events.

Reading the chapter focused on Atom got my very excited to look into replacing the home-grown/custom solution the company I work at has developed to solve the same problem (delivering a feed of events over a RESTful API)...however, I started doing some follow up research and found that development/interest in the various Atom libraries out there (like Apache Abdera and ROME) seem to suffer from dwindling community interest.

Is Atom still being used for this purpose (event feeds), or has another solution come into favor?

Comment: Not sure of what the appropriate stackoverflow protocol is here, but I believe I have answered my own question with a little follow up research.  The short answer to my question(s) appears to be "Collection+JSON".  i.e. folks in 2014 are solving the same kinds of problems they used to solve via Atom/AtomPub by utilizing "Collection+JSON".